# Ncurses is mysteriously using all my CPU for no reason

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to write a program like nethack with ncurses. The program works fine, draws me a box and everything perfectly while not eating up much of my CPU. After I added the `while(true)` loop, it doesn't draw my box and it eats up 100% of my CPU when I move my "character".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
int main(){
    std::pair<int,int> csr_pos{1,1};
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);
    WINDOW *win = newwin(50,80,0,0);
    if(has_colors()){
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_CYAN,COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(2,COLOR_RED,COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_RED);
        init_pair(4,COLOR_YELLOW,COLOR_BLACK);
    }
    /*
    wattron(win,COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvwaddch(win,25,41,'@');
    wattroff(win,COLOR_PAIR(1));
    */
    for(int i = 0; i<80; i++){
        mvwaddch(win,0,i,'#');
        mvwaddch(win,49,i,'#');
        wrefresh(win);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i<49; i++){
        mvwaddch(win,i,0,'#');
        mvwaddch(win,i,79,'#');
        wrefresh(win);
    }
    while(true){
        mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
        int ch = getch();
        if(ch==KEY_LEFT){
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,' ');
            csr_pos.second--;
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
        }
        if(ch==KEY_RIGHT){
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,' ');
            csr_pos.second++;
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
        }
        wrefresh(win);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
```

Let's take a look at what the curses manual page says about this:

```
 nodelay
   The nodelay option causes getch to be a non-blocking call.  If no input
   is  ready,  getch  returns ERR.  If disabled (bf is FALSE), getch waits
   until a key is pressed.
```

If that wasn't clear: in nodelay mode `getch` does not wait for a keypress. It returns immediately.

Let's see what the shown code does next:

```
while(true){
    mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
    int ch = getch();

// ...
```

So, this now becomes a 100% CPU bound infinite loop. `getch` always returns immediately. If neither of the two keys that the following code checks for are pressed, this `while` loop immediately runs again, and you're back where you started, over and over again.

And that's the reason why the shown code "eats up 100%" of the CPU.

`nodelay` mode is meant to be used with additional logic that `poll()`s or `select()`s until there's a keypress, and `getch` gets called only when there's an actual key to be read.

Comment: Ok so, I commented out that `nodelay()`, it solved my cpu problem, but i still don't get why my box isn't being drawn.

Comment: That would be another, unrelated question better addressed in a new question..

Comment: Your box isn't drawn because the implicit refresh of `stdscr` by `getch()` is overwriting `win`. Change it to `wgetch(win)`.